# Segmentation fault while using smart pointers

Tags: c++11, memory-management, memory-leaks, smart-pointers

I get an  error of ->
Segmentation fault while accessing address 0x00007ff8bf611980 (_ZNSt10_weakptrIN10prometheus11CollectableELN9_gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE2EEC1ERKS4_+0x1b) [0x7fff8bee28215]

My code lies below-
Also I am sure the source of the error is the line "ex->register(registry);"(commented as problematic line) as when I comment it the error dosen't occur.

```
 void Family::MakeGauge3(std::string s1, std::string s2, const 
 std::map<string,string>& labels, MyExposer* ex)
 {  auto registry = make_shared<prometheus::Registry>();
    gauge_family= &(prometheus::BuildGauge().Name(s1).Help(s2).
    Labels(labels).Register(*registry));
    ex->register(registry); //problematic line
 }
```

The register function in the MyExposer class is->

```
 void MyExposer::register(std::shared_ptr<prometheus::Registry> reg)
 {
 exp ->RegisterCollectable(reg);
 }
```

exp is a private member of class MyExposer defined as->

Exposer* exp;   //Exposer is another class

Also class Registry is publicly inherited from my class called Collectable.

```
 void Exposer::RegisterCollectable(const 
 std::weak_ptr<prometheus::Collectable>& 
 collectable)
 {   collectables_.push_back(collectable);
 }
```

where collectable_is a private member defined in Exposer class as->

```
std::vector<std::weak_ptr<prometheus::Collectable>> collectables_;
```

Comment: What does this line do: `gauge_family= &(prometheus::BuildGauge().Name(s1).Help(s2).Labels(labels).Register(*registry));` ? It seems to be touching `registry` in some way. I don't see anything wrong with the rest of the code.

Comment: Sorry that problem is resolved. exp in MyExposer* was pointing to a stack allocated object and so was causing the problem. I made it point to a heap allocated object and all is fine !!